# What is the significance of negative potential energy

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy, definition

I've learnt this statement as a fact **potential energy of bound systems is negative**

I am interested in knowing the significance or physical meaning of this statement.particulary for electrostatic systems

---

I searched this on net for system of charges

#`A negative potential energy means that work must be done against the electric field in moving the charges apart!`

#  `Assuming potential at infinity to be zero if electrostatic potential energy of the system is negative then net positive work by an external agent was required to assemble the system of charges`

These two statements were doubtful to me and I don't know how to believe these without proper justification available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement is correct. The second is wrong.

A simple definition of the potential energy of a system is the amount of work it can do because of the relative positions of its parts. So if a system has negative potential energy with respect to when the parts of the system are separated to infinity, then work must be put in by an external force in order to separate the parts to infinity. This would apply, for example, to a system consisting of a positive charge and a negative charge.

In the second statement, "assemble" should be replaced by "take apart".

Answer (score 0):

> I've learnt this statement as a fact potential energy of bound systems
> is negative
>
> I am interested in knowing the significance or physical meaning of
> this statement.particulary for electrostatic systems

It's largely a matter of *convention*. Let me explain. For example:

the gravitational potential energy in a central gravitational field [is given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_energy#:%7E:text=Gravitational%20energy%20or%20gravitational%20potential,objects%20fall%20towards%20each%20other.):

$$U=-\frac{GMm}{r}$$

We know that the work needed to move an object from $r_1$ to $r_2$ (where $r_2> r_1$) is:

$$W=\Delta U=U_2-U_1$$
$$W=-\frac{GMm}{r_2}-\Big(-\frac{GMm}{r_1}\Big)$$
$$W=\frac{GMm}{r_1}-\frac{GMm}{r_2}=GMm\Big(\frac{1}{r_1}-\frac{1}{r_2}\Big)$$

So that **correctly**:

$$W>0\text{ because } r_2> r_1$$

The same holds true for a charged particle in a central Coulombic field, for example.

The truth is that the **exact** value of the potential energy is almost impossible to know and usually doesn't need to be known because *we're more interested in changes in potential energy than absolute values*. E.g. an object in a central gravitational field will also contain other energies like chemical energy, nuclear binding energy etc. These energies are usually not known. For that reason it's possible to choose a reference point, e.g. $U=0 \text{ for }r=+\infty$. The $U(r)$ values, calibrated against that reference point, are negative.

The values $U(r)$ are thus arbitrary but the values for $\Delta U$ are always exact.

Comment: I got it but can you explain 2nd # statement

Comment: Tell me the first three words of that statement?

Comment: Assuming potential at infinity to be zero if electrostatic potential energy of the system is negative then net positive work by an external agent was required to assemble the system of charge

Comment: Yes, that last statement is correct.